# When to create a generator or return simply a list in Python?

Tags: python, generator

I have this kind of instance method:

```
def list_records(self,race_type,year=0):
    yearnow= datetime.now().year
    yearlist = [yearnow - i for i in range(4)]
    if not year:
        for y in yearlist:
            if self.records:
                yield self.records[utils.dateracetype_to_DBcolumn(y,str(race_type))]
            else:
                yield None
    else:
        if self.records:
            yield self.records[utils.dateracetype_to_DBcolumn(year,str(race_type))]
        else:
            yield None
```

1. I am calling it mainly through list comprehension,
   but I could return it simply as a list, what is the most pythonic
   way to do this? What would be the reasons to chose one method or the
   other?
2. let's say I'll go with a generator, should I
   turn the 2 last 'yield' into return values as there will be only one
   value to be returned?
3. Is there a more optimized way to code this method, as I have the
   feeling there's too much nested conditions/loop in there?
4. Is there a Python convention to name generators? something like
   'gen...'

Thanks

Comment: 1) Depends on the context, which is missing in this question. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic]. 3) I've seen much worse. I'd probably create 2 sub-functions for `list_records`, but whether that makes it any better is a matter of taste. 4) All Python conventions are in the PEP. However, generators are usually not named. Their result is named. How the result was created is irrelevant. The naming you propose smells like Hungarian notation gone wrong and I'd advise against it.

Comment: The exception to naming generators is of-course if you create a function which yeals the result of a generator. In that case it would be totally ok to name the function `generate_whatever`.

Comment: The context is flexible for this case, I could either manage a list or a generator. Regarding the naming, in a few week I want to remember at first glance that this method has to be used as a generator, but I assume that yield keyword will help me reminding ;)

Comment: @Mast What context is missing from the question?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8905).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you are going to need the whole list for some reason, then make a list. But if you only need one item at a time, use a generator. The reasons for preferring generators are (i) you only need the memory for one item at a time; (ii) if the items are coming from a file or network connection or database then generators give you some parallelism because you can be processing the first item without having to wait for all items to arrive; (iii) generators can handle infinite streams of items.
2. There is no special convention for naming generators in Python. It is best to name a function after the things it generates.
3. Instead of:

   ```
   [yearnow - i for i in range(4)]
   ```

   write:

   ```
   range(yearnow, yearnow - 4, -1)
   ```
4. The duplicated code could be avoided like this:

   ```
   if year:
       year_range = (year,)
   else:
       year_now = datetime.now().year
       year_range = range(year_now, year_now - 4, -1)
   for y in year_range:
       if self.records:
           yield self.records[utils.dateracetype_to_DBcolumn(y, str(race_type))]
       else:
           yield None
   ```

   (But I don't recommend implementing it like this, as I'll explain below.)
5. It is conventional to use `None` as the default value for an argument like `year`. A default like `year=0` might be confused with a legitimate value for `year`. For example, in [astronomical year numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_year_numbering) there is a year zero, and how would you pass this to your function?
6. Instead of yielding an exceptional value (here `None`) when there are no results to generate, just generate no results. The problem with exceptional values is that the caller might forget to check for them, whereas it is usually straightforward to handle the case of no results.
7. I don't think it's a good idea to use `datetime.now().year` for the case where the caller doesn't specify a year. The problem is that close to midnight on 31st December, there is a race: the current year might be 2018 just before the call to `list_records` happens, and 2019 just after. What should `list_records` return in this case? The [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says,

   > In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

   so it would be better to avoid this problem by requiring the caller to specify the year.
8. The function does two different things: it generates the record for a year (if a year was specified), or it generates records from the last four years (if no year was specified). The [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) suggests that these two things should be implemented by two functions:

   ```
   def year_record(self, race_type, year):
       """Return the record for race_type and year.
       Raise IndexError if there are no records.

       """
       return self.records[utils.dateracetype_to_DBcolumn(year, str(race_type))]

   def recent_records(self, race_type, year, n=4):
       """Generate the records for race_type for the n years up to (and
       including) year, in reverse order.

       """
       for y in range(year, year - n, -1):
           try:
               yield self.year_record(race_type, y)
           except IndexError:
               pass
   ```
9. If the caller needs to know whether there was a record for each year, then I recommend generating the necessary data explicitly, like this:

   ```
   def recent_records(self, race_type, year, n=4):
       """Generate the records for race_type for the n years up to (and
       including) year, in reverse order. For each year, generate a tuple
       (year, have_record, record) where have_record is True if there
       is a record for the given year, or False if not.

       """
       for y in range(year, year - n, -1):
           try:
               yield year, True, self.year_record(race_type, y)
           except IndexError:
               yield year, False, None
   ```

   Then the caller can write:

   ```
   for year, have_record, record in self.recent_records(...):
       if have_record:
           # ...
   ```

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks! Regarding 2) why more range than list comprehension? Because it is a generator itself?

Comment: Another point: I had put a yield None since I need to know when no year record exists to manage the way I will display it (should be '-'). So maybe instead of pass I could write yield None?

Comment: See §9 of the revised answer